# I want to execute this job every 2nd and 4th week Monday to Friday

Tags: cron

I want to execute this job every 2nd and 4th week Monday to Friday:

```
05 17 8-14,22-28 * 1-5 runBidWonReport.sh
```

I want to execute this job every 1st and 3rd week Monday to Saturday:

```
05 17 1-7,15-21 * 1-6 runBidWonReport.sh
```

Comment: that looks like the same script on both sets of weeks?

Comment: Do you mean 2nd and 4th week of month or of year? or do you mean that every other week it changes from mon-fri to mon-sat?

Comment: Found this conversation about that very subject:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683387/run-every-2nd-and-4th-saturday-of-the-month

Answer (score 1):

Run it every day and in the script check if it should run or not. If not - exit. It will be easy to do the check in bash.